# 80's B&W Comic "Soon"

Tags: story-identification, comics

Very sure it was back in the 80's. It was a black and white comic with glossy colour cover, printed on fairly cheap paper and featured a few stories.

I remember that one of the last stories was about an earth conquered by aliens and the people were all slaves. They then start receiving a message "soon". It turns out that a few of the military had survived and had built a huge ship capable of winning back the Earth. I had kept the comic for at least a decade before it disappeared. 20 years later I still wish to see it again. Any help in narrowing it down will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this one has been asked recently...

Comment: Sorry, I did look back then and once more today. I was unable to find anything even down to just searching on here for the term "soon"